# Making a button visible based on number of records in datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using jquery datatable in asp.net mvc and i want to show a submit button which will be saving the data to the database only if there is atleast one row in the datatable.

I am trying this code, however its not working

```
<tr id="trbtnSubmit">
    <td colspan="9" align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Save" 
            class="btn btn-edit btn-text" />
    </td>
</tr>
    
<script>
    var PopUp, dataTable;
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable = $("#tblCustomerList").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Customer/GetCustomers",
                "type": "GET",
                "data": "json"
            },
            "lengthChange": false,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Number" },
                { "data": "Name" },
                { "data": "fileName" },
                { "data": "mD5Hash" },
                { "data": "dataSizeInGB" },
                { 
                  "data": "Id",
                  "render": function () {
                      return "<a href='#'><i class='fa fa-eye'></a></i><a href='#' style='margin-left:5px'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a><a href='#' style='margin-left:5px'><i class='fa fa-trash'></a></i>";
                  },
                  "orderable": false,
                  "width": "40px"
                },
            ],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No Customers , click on <b>New Customer</b> to add Customers"
            }
        });

        var table = $('#tblCustomerList').DataTable();
    
        if (!table.data().any())  {
            $('#trbtnSubmit').hide();
        } else {
            $('#trbtnSubmit').show();
        }       
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify the version of `datatables`, I assume it's v1.10.

And there are 2 side notes I want to make before going into your problem:

1. Difference between `.datatable()` and `.DataTable()`
2. Enable server-side processing

#### Difference Between .datatable() and .DataTable()

I saw you declared another variable, `var table`, at the bottom of your sample code to get another instance of DataTables and check if there is any data? You actually don't need to.

`.DataTable()` returns a DataTables API instance, while `.datatable()` returns a jQuery object.

So if you intent to make usages on the DataTables APIs after you initialize the table, you can just use the varirable you declared from the beginning, `var dataTable` since you used `.DataTable()` way.

#### Enable Server-side Processing

Server-side processing is enabled by turning on the `serverSide` option, and configuring the `ajax` option. You're missing the first one, whose default is `false`.

So you might need to add `serverSide` option in your code:

```js
dataTable = $("#tblCustomerList").DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

Enough said. Now looking at your problem ...

#### DataTables Callbacks

There are many ways to achieve what you want to do, and I like to use callbacks so that you can configure your DataTables in one place.

There are [lots of callbacks](https://datatables.net/reference/option/) you can use, and the one I would use is `drawCallback`:

```js
dataTable = $("#tblCustomerList").DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ...,
    language: {
        emptyTable: "No Customers , click on <b>New Customer</b> to add Customers"
    },
    drawCallback: function(settings) {
        $('#trbtnSubmit').toggle(settings.aoData.length > 0);
    }
});
```

Hopefully my code is readable enough without any additional explanations :)

Comment: Thanks. However i am not getting the expected result. Basically after implementing this,  the submit button is not visible at all even though the number of records in the data table is 0 or more.Also i am getting the pages numbers for the data table as well(even though i set the page length as 10).

Comment: @krishna: I see what you meant now. Please see my update. I changed "infoCallback" to "drawCallback" so that you don't have to re-construct the information bar on the lower left corner after getting the total count information.